# specify armeabi-v7a, but jni continue to build x86_64

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I am doing jni by using the third lib, where jni lib: libLivenessDetectorJni.so depend on liblivenessdetector.so(a third lib only in armeabi-v7a).

I specify abi build only under armeabi-v7a in gradle:

```
externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
            cppFlags "-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions"
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
            }
        }
```

But after building armeabi-v7a(success), it continues to build x86_64(fail), why?

```
> Task :common-silent:externalNativeBuildDebug
Build LivenessDetectorJni armeabi-v7a
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/LivenessDetectorJni.dir/LivenessDetectorJni.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library /home/jnitest/common-silent/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libLivenessDetectorJni.so

> Task :common-silent:mergeDebugJniLibFolders
> Task :common-silent:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug
> Task :common-silent:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug
> Task :common-silent:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForDebug

> Task :app:externalNativeBuildDebug FAILED
Build LivenessDetectorJni x86_64
ninja: error: '/home/jnitest/common-silent/src/main/jniLibs/x86_64/liblivenessdetector.so', needed by '/homejnitest/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86_64/libLivenessDetectorJni.so', missing and no known rule to make it
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Who can help me config it? Thanks.

BTW, after I remove all the abiFilters and save the build log, I found that jni is compiled 2 times. Why?

```
cat log | grep LivenessDetectorJni --color
Build LivenessDetectorJni x86_64
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/LivenessDetectorJni.dir/LivenessDetectorJni.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library /home/jnitest/common-silent/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86_64/libLivenessDetectorJni.so
Build LivenessDetectorJni x86
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/LivenessDetectorJni.dir/LivenessDetectorJni.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library /home/jnitest/common-silent/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86/libLivenessDetectorJni.so
Build LivenessDetectorJni arm64-v8a
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/LivenessDetectorJni.dir/LivenessDetectorJni.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library /home/jnitest/common-silent/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/arm64-v8a/libLivenessDetectorJni.so
Build LivenessDetectorJni armeabi-v7a
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/LivenessDetectorJni.dir/LivenessDetectorJni.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library /home/jnitest/common-silent/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libLivenessDetectorJni.so
Build LivenessDetectorJni x86_64
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/LivenessDetectorJni.dir/LivenessDetectorJni.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library /home/jnitest/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86_64/libLivenessDetectorJni.so
Build LivenessDetectorJni x86
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/LivenessDetectorJni.dir/LivenessDetectorJni.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library /home/jnitest/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86/libLivenessDetectorJni.so
Build LivenessDetectorJni arm64-v8a
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/LivenessDetectorJni.dir/LivenessDetectorJni.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library /home/jnitest/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/arm64-v8a/libLivenessDetectorJni.so
Build LivenessDetectorJni armeabi-v7a
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/LivenessDetectorJni.dir/LivenessDetectorJni.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library /home/jnitest/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libLivenessDetectorJni.so
```

If I use abiFilters, then the log is changed as:

```
cat log | grep LivenessDetectorJni --color
Build LivenessDetectorJni armeabi-v7a
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/LivenessDetectorJni.dir/LivenessDetectorJni.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library /home/jnitest/common-silent/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libLivenessDetectorJni.so
Build LivenessDetectorJni x86_64
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/LivenessDetectorJni.dir/LivenessDetectorJni.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library /home/jnitest/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86_64/libLivenessDetectorJni.so
Build LivenessDetectorJni x86
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/LivenessDetectorJni.dir/LivenessDetectorJni.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library /home/jnitest/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86/libLivenessDetectorJni.so
Build LivenessDetectorJni arm64-v8a
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/LivenessDetectorJni.dir/LivenessDetectorJni.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library /home/jnitest/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/arm64-v8a/libLivenessDetectorJni.so
Build LivenessDetectorJni armeabi-v7a
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/LivenessDetectorJni.dir/LivenessDetectorJni.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library /home/jnitest/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libLivenessDetectorJni.so
```

Answer (score 2):

abiFilter is part of 'ndk'block.

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    externalNativeBuild {
      //cmake {...}
      ndkBuild {
         abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a'
      }
    }


  }
```

See details here.
https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/gradle-external-native-builds#specify-abi

Comment: Thanks your quick answer. I modify gradle as         externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
            cppFlags "-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions"
//            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
            }
        }

        ndk{
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a"
        }, but same error

Comment: Use defaultConfig.externalNativeBuild.ndkBuild block as updated in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because I link c++ in the android project 2 times, the project builds 2 times.